# javascript TypeError: Cannot find function startsWith

Tags: javascript, ant

I have a javascript function:

```
           string.prototype.startsWith = function(str) {
               return (this.indexOf(str) === 0);
           }
```

and when I run it on something whose typeof returns `object`, it works.  When I run it on something whose typeof returns `string`, I get:

`javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function startsWith. (<Unknown source>#29) in <Unknown source> at line number 29`

Does anyone know whats going on?  I don't even understand why the instance type of the first thing I'm using is object.  It's the result of a readLine call, shouldn't that be string?

```
<target name="analyze">
    <script language="javascript">

    <![CDATA[
            importClass(java.io.File);
            importClass(java.io.FileReader)
            importClass(java.io.BufferedReader)
            //setup the source directory
            dir = project.getProperty("PROJECT_HOME");
            fs = project.createDataType("fileset");
            fs.setDir(new File(dir));
            //only analyze java files
            fs.setIncludes("**/*.java");
            echo = project.createTask("echo");
            //iterate over files found
            srcFiles = fs.getDirectoryScanner(project).getIncludedFiles();
            for (i = 0; i < srcFiles.length; i++) {
                var filename = srcFiles[i];
                inFile  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(dir + "/" + filename)));
                while ((line = inFile.readLine()) != null) {
                   if(line.startsWith("package")) {
                       packageStr = line.substr(8);
                       while((line = inFile.readLine()) != null) {
                           if(line.startsWith("import") && line.endsWith("Foo;")) {
                               //strip out the leading import in 'import x.y.z'
                               var importStr = line.substr(7);
                               importStr = importStr.substr(0, importStr.lastIndexOf('.'));
                               if(!importStr.startsWith(packageStr)) { <---- FAILS!
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
                }
                inFile.close();
           }

           String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) {
               return (this.indexOf(str) === 0);
           }

           String.prototype.endsWith = function(str) {
               var lastIndex = this.lastIndexOf(str);
               return (lastIndex != -1) && (lastIndex + str.length == this.length);
           }

    ]]>
    </script>
</target>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you call `starstWith` function before you define it. Perhaps you should put two function definitions ahead of `for` block. In this way they are evaluated before they are called.

Comment: That was it!  javascript sucks.

Answer (score 2):

try with capital S :

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) {
               return (this.indexOf(str) === 0);
           }
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I did both and it didn't work.